# Put related list in lightning tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-tab

I have a lightning record detail page. I have some related lists. What I would like to understand is if I can put one of the related lists under the activity tab. Attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'Related List - Single' from the list of Standard Components under your tab. Use the properties panel on the right to select Activities related list. Make sure your desired related list exists on the page layout. See below for clarity.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you create your "own" Lightning Record page or edit your existing one via the app builder, you can use a tab component, and within it you can add the components you are looking for (including related lists)

[image]

Comment: you can do that also if you edit your default record page - edit the tabs and add a component before the activity component

Comment: i am not being able to understand how to add the related list @glls

Comment: @ItaiShmida I am very new to lightning. What I want is to have a related component under activity. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: @user55791, considering that you have been posting questions tagged lightning for 2 months now, you should consider learning the basics at the very least from Trailheads, additionally, you are not very keen on accepting answers once they have been provided to you.